# How to change Sonar Qube theme

Tags: sonarqube, themes

I need to change the Sonar Qube report theme. I have the default theme for the report but I want to customize it.
Please find the attachment for demo purpose. I have report with theme like this: 
[image]

but I want to make it change like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJfqy.png]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to regress your project landing page approximately 3 major SonarQube versions. That's simply not possible without starting over with a 3.x SonarQube instance.

The standardized project homepage (your first screenshot) was introduced in the 5.x series, and customizable dashboards were dropped in 6.2. If you want the features of a modern version of SonarQube, you'll have to live with the benefits of the upgraded interface as well.